# Changing the textColor when the state changes in TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, selector, textcolor

Hey I am trying to change the `textColor` in `TextView` when the user press it. I am trying to make something like hyperlink button in `Windows 8`. I have this selector in `res/color folder`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_hovered="true">
        <color android:color="@color/darkBlue"/>
    </item>
    <item  android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/lightBlue"/>
    </item>
    <item android:color="@color/black"/> <!-- default color -->
</selector>
```

and I use it like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw_language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/language_label"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:text="@string/default_language_label"
        android:textColor="@color/language_button"

        />
```

In activity when I get the reference to this textView I set `mLanguage.setPaintFlags(mLanguage.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);`

to get underlined text. And the app crashes using this. If I set

```
android:background="@color/language_button"
```

Instead of `textColor` it works fine. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add that if I ser android:background the it changes the background. And I want to change textColor.

Comment: do you want to change just text color or color and text style (underline in this case)?

Comment: isn't your problem solved yet with answers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute to your TextView like below

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    style="@drawable/language_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

`style="@drawable/language_button"` is your selector file. I have defined that file in `drawable/stack.xml` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    mMainView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);//set the color here
        }

    });
```